# Sending POST request in iPhone using ASIHTTPRequest 1.6.2

Tags: iphone, ipad, asihttprequest

I am using ASIHTTPRequest 1.6.2 lib for all http transactions in IPhone. But i dont know, how can i post the data with ASIHTTPRequest in iPhone?

Can you please give me the code snippet which will work in in iphone? 
I am using the following code for this. But i am getting response code as 0. Please help me to understand where i am going wrong.

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setPostValue:inputXml forKey:@"inputXml"];
 [request setPostValue:@"qftS6TJN343343V84hw=" forKey:@"key"];
 [request setPostValue:@"1.2" forKey:@"version"];
 [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
 [request startAsynchronous];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [ASIFormDataRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use):

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/ben/Desktop/ben.jpg" forKey:@"photo"];
```

Comment: @barfoon.. I am getting the response code as 0. i have edited the question and added the code. plz look into it and suggest any other extra parameter need to set.

Comment: It is possible to set ASINetworkQueue for multiple image upload to server

Answer (score 1):

Here's the how to page.  It covers all types of requests such as get, form post, custom post, put, etc...

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use

Here's how to set it up in your XCode project:

http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/Setup-instructions

Those instructions and snippets should work in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the sample code...

```
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [[ASIHTTPRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
    [request appendPostData:[reqString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setTimeOutSeconds:60]; 
    [request startAsynchronous];
```

You will get detail guidance from [**here**](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use).

Answer (score 0):

```
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:]];

        NSMutableDictionary *dicData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:1];
        [dicData setObject:txtPassword.text forKey:@"Password"];
        [dicData setObject:txtEmailID.text forKey:@"Email"];

        [request setPostBody:[[[self parseJsonFromObject:dicData] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] mutableCopy]];

        [request setRequestHeaders:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"application/json", @"Content-Type", nil]];

        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(signUpWithEmailFinish:)];
        [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(signUpWithEmailFail:)];
        [request startAsynchronous];

       (void)signUpWithEmailFinish:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request
       {

           if (request.responseStatusCode == 200)
           {

        NSDictionary *responseMessage = [self objectFromJson:request.responseString];
        NSLog(@"ResponseMEssage=%@",responseMessage);
        if (responseMessage)
        {

            if ([responseMessage objectForKey:@"user"] == nil)
            {

                NSLog(@"duplication not allowed");
                [self animation:0];

                return;
            }

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:NOTIFICATION_LOGIN_SUCCESS object:nil];
            NSLog(@"Registration Complete");
            UserLoginPage *userLogin=[[UserLoginPage alloc]init];

            [self.navigationController pushViewController:userLogin animated:YES];
            return;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add some detail explaining why your code answers the question?  What did you do differently?